# How to write test case for a method addProduct in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to write test case for a method `addItem` may be in `product.component.spec.ts` file . This is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  productName:any
  quantity:any

 public data:any[]=[
    {
        "ID": 101,
        "Product": "Moto G",
        "Quantity": 2,
    },
    {
        "ID": 102,
        "Product": "TV",
        "Quantity": 4,
    },
    {
        "ID": 105,
        "Product": "Watch",
        "Quantity": 2,
    },   
    ]
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
  } 

  addItem() {
    this.data.push({ Product: this.productName, Quantity: this.quantity});
  }  
}
```

I started writing in `product.component.spec.ts` file

```
  describe('ProductComponent', () => {
    let component: ProductComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductComponent>;

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    });   
  });
```

`product.component.spec.ts` file

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product.component';

describe('ProductComponent', () => {
  let component: ProductComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductComponent>;

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ProductComponent
    ]
});

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProductComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
 
});
```

Comment: This can barely be considered an attempt at solving the problem, have you read https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you should do it.

```
describe('ProductComponent', () => {
  let component: ProductComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductComponent>;

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ProductComponent
    ]
});

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProductComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.data = [{productName : "p1", quantity : 3}]
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should add items to "data"', () => {
     expect(component.data.length).toBe(1); // since you have initialized the variable
     component.productName = "Prod1";
     component.quantity = 1;
     component.addItem();  // this will trigger the method
     expect(component.data.length).toBe(4); // this will show that the entry was added in "this.data"
  });  
 
});
```

I would also suggest you to go through [this intro article of mine](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7) to understand unit testing in `angular`.  There are few links attached to this article as well , which can help you understand the best practices of testing a component. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Let check it.

Comment: @R15 : sure, keep me posted if some more info is requuired

Comment: It's working for me. Just one thing, I have declared `data` on top. Can also I write test for that? If yes.. Is it possible for you to add that.. Instead of asking new question :)

Comment: What I came to know If I write test case of array declaration, then my hard code data wont work for testing output at http://localhost:9876/?id=14595384 . Table showing now 0 records.

Comment: @R15 : make you have done `fixture.detectCHanges()` to let the angular know that it has to revisit the rendering

Comment: `fixture.detectCHanges() ` already there. It shows same result.

Comment: I didn't needed that, I just asked.

Answer (score 1):

A testcase always includes 4-5 steps:

1. Tear up
2. Data preperation
3. Execution
4. Verification
5. (optional) Tear down

What you already have is the first step. For the second step you need to prepare the required fields, which are `data`, `quantity` and `productName`.

```
component.productName = 'Awesome Product';
component.quantity = 3;
component.data = [];
```

The third steps only executes the method you want to test.

```
component.addItem();
```

With the fourth step you check the result, which is now the extended array.

```
expect(component.data).toEqual([{ Product: 'Awesome Product', Quantity: 3 }]);
```

Comment: Do I need to wrap up this inside `describe('ProductComponent', () =>`

Comment: What is currently in your description should actually be in a beforeEach section. And add another description for the addItem test

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I add/integrate this in `spec.ts` file